# Find sub elements that differ in two collections in Linq

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

How can I do a Linq query for this?

I have two xml documents, doc1.xml, and doc2.xml. How can I find for each "file" element in doc1 where doc2 has a "file" element with the exact same "path" attribute, but any "link" child element of this "file" in doc1 has an "absolutepath" attribute that is NOT the same as one or more "absolutepath" attributes in the corresponding "file" element in doc2?

simple example:

doc1:

```
<doc>
  <file path="c:\temp\A.xml">
    <link absolutepath="c:\temp\B.xml"/>
    <link absolutepath="c:\temp\C.xml"/>
  </file>
  <file path="c:\temp\C.xml"> <!--This should match, because it's child link absolutepath is not the same as child link absolutepath of the corresponding file with the same path in doc2-->
    <link absolutepath="c:\temp\D.xml"/>
    <link absolutepath="c:\temp\F.xml"/>
  </file>
</doc>
```

doc2:

```
<doc>
  <file path="c:\temp\A.xml">
    <link absolutepath="c:\temp\B.xml"/>
    <link absolutepath="c:\temp\C.xml"/>
  </file>
  <file path="c:\temp\C.xml">
    <link absolutepath="c:\temp\D.xml"/>
    <link absolutepath="c:\temp\E.xml"/>
  </file>
</doc>
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: Edited the example xml to show what I mean by multiple links for each file element. So what I want is each file in doc1 that has a link element with an absolutepath that is not found in a link element in doc2. So there are actually the same number of links in both, but the absolutepath may differ sometimes and that's what I want to find and extract those files where there is such a difference in the link elements.

Here's my attempt to modify the query suggested by Jon, to extract multiple links, but I think I'm doing it wrong, because I don't get the correct result from the Except query afterwards:

```
   var files = from file in doc1.Descendants("file")

                select new
                {
                    file = file.Attribute("path").Value,
                    link = file.Elements("link").Attributes("absolutepath")
                };
    var oldfiles = from file in doc2.Descendants("file")
                from link in file.Elements("link")
                select new
                {
                    file = file.Attribute("path").Value,
                    link = file.Elements("link").Attributes("absolutepath")
                };
    //Get the ones that are different between them
    var missing = files.Except(oldfiles);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would start with the XML part. I originally made this more complicated than it needs to be, but I think you can just use:

```
var files = from file in document.Descendants("file")
            from link in file.Elements("link")
            select new { file = file.Attribute("path").Value,
                         link = link.Attribute("absolutepath").Value };
```

Then if you have `files1` and `files2` (the above query applied to each document) you can just do:

```
var extraFiles = files1.Except(files2);
```

EDIT: To get back to the link elements for those files, you can use:

```
var linkElements = from link in file.Descendants("link")
                   join extra in extraFiles on 
                         new { file = link.Parent.Attribute("path").Value,
                               link = link.Attribute("absolutepath").Value }
                         equals extra
                   select link;
```

It's a bit of a shame to query the document again, but there we go...

(I've selected the link element rather than the file element so you can get to exactly the right bit - you can always choose the parent element to get to the file.)

EDIT: Okay, if there are multiple link elements and you just want to find files with missing elements, that's actually pretty easy from what we've got:

```
var justFiles = new HashSet<string>(extraFiles.Select(x => x.file).Distinct());
var fileElements = from element in file.Descendants("file")
                   where justFiles.Contains((string) element.Attribute("path")
                   select element;
```

Comment: Thank you, that's great! But is there any way I can actually get the file elements as XElement out of the query? That's what I use next in the code to do stuff to each XElement...

Comment: @Anders: It's *slightly* tricky to do so, because of the way `Except` works. You could put the element into the projection but then use `ExceptBy` from MoreLINQ...

Comment: Ok, but so is there an easy way to do another query, getting the file XElements from doc1 where their path attribute values match the string file in the result of your query?

Comment: @Anders: Yes, that's *reasonably* straightforward - will edit to show that. Seems a shame to query it again...

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just discovered a problem when I tried it out though: I forgot to mention that each file can have many link elements, and I need to match the files where ANY link element is not matched in the other collection of link elements... Can it be modified to do that?

Comment: @Anders: That's actually pretty easy, given what we've got. Will edit.

Comment: We have different definitions of what is easy :-), but thanks. Still, I'm not sure I was clear enough, because if I didn't misunderstand your answer, then I think you may have misunderstood the question. I edited it to make myself clearer. So there won't be any file elements with missing links per se, only link elements with different absolutepath values... I would assume the first query (var files) has to extract the multiple links first of all, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Anders: No, my query will work - because the first part would find in your example `{ file = "c:\temp\C.xml", link = "c:\temp\F.xml" }`, and then the last part of the answer would go from that to the `<file>` element corresponding to that. Note that there are two "from" clauses in the first query, which means you get a separate result for every link within every file.

Comment: Ok, I can't wrap my head around that, but I'll try it and see, disregard my last edit to the question then :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks, it seems to be working up to the Except part, giving me the correct result set. However, I get some error in the last expression - the compiler doesn't understand where the x in "x.Attribute" comes from...